# Certificate format

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

Analyzing some payload I faced up to one which contains a string like this :

`VeriSign, Inc.10UVeriSign Trust Network1:08U1(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only1E0CU VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5150318000000Z150630235959Z0`

Could anyone help me to understand what is the code that start with `G`?

The payload probably comes from a malicious traffic.

Comment: what kind of payload? what's the rest of the context?

Comment: This is still unclear - are you saying this is from a packet capture? What contained this string? What's after the string?

Comment: I think you will find what you are looking for here: https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're basically looking at the raw data of a certificate signed by a Verisign root,** which is not surprising if you're looking at network traces.  It doesn't imply anything about the rest of the stream.

"G5" is part of the name of a certificate -

[**Root 3
VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5**](https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots)

In this case that's actually the Issuer of the certificate you're actually looking at.

The two long numbers terminated with Z that follow (`150318000000Z150630235959Z`) are the Validity period, as per [RFC 5280 ss 4.1.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.5):

> The certificate validity period is the time interval during which the
> CA warrants that it will maintain information about the status of the
> certificate.  The field is represented as a SEQUENCE of two dates: the
> date on which the certificate validity period begins (notBefore) and
> the date on which the certificate validity period ends (notAfter).
> Both notBefore and notAfter may be encoded as UTCTime or
> GeneralizedTime.

The Z indicates that they are using UTCTime ([RFC 5280 ss 4.1.2.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.5.1)):

> The universal time type, UTCTime, is a standard ASN.1 type intended
> for representation of dates and time.  UTCTime specifies the year
> through the two low-order digits and time is specified to the
> precision of one minute or one second.  UTCTime includes either Z (for
> Zulu, or Greenwich Mean Time) or a time differential.
>
> For the purposes of this profile, UTCTime values MUST be expressed in
> Greenwich Mean Time (Zulu) and MUST include seconds (i.e., times are
> YYMMDDHHMMSSZ), even where the number of seconds is zero.

Comment: ok, It is what I would to know, now I'm wondering if I can extract from this kind of payload any others info about the certificate like fingerprint or serial number. thanks again